# How do I format texts that were processed by OCR?

Tags: linux, text-processing, scripting, ocr

Let's say that I want to connect all the paragraphs that are broken by the citations that start with (1), (2), (3), (4), (5). How would I express/automate this in bash? Keep in mind there are at most 5 citations in a single page which means I have to keep in mind all the combinations of 1, 1-2, 1-2-3, 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3-4-5.

Example:

> parler en usage dans tous les temps et dans tous les pays, formaient
> avec les nouveaux principes le contraste le plus frappant. Suivant le
> système dont nous parlons, le pouvoir souverain, ou du moins la source
> du pouvoir, est dans le peuple, c'est-à-dire, dans le corps des
> sujets; car ce sont eux qui doivent avoir fondé l'État par leur
> réunion. La masse du peuple est le véritable souverain , le maître
> réel, le summus imperans ; c'est en elle seule que la majesté réside
> tout entière (1). Les princes que l?on regardait jadis comme des
> seigneurs indépendans, se trouvent changés en simples serviteurs ou
> employés de leurs peuples (2); car celui qui recoit un pouvoir est
> nécessairement subordonné à celui qui le confère (3). L'autorité
>
> (1) Du Contrat social, L. I. ch. 1, et mille autres ou vrages pareils.
> On est forcé de soutenir cette proposition , du moment où l?on
> considère le peuple (l'agrégation des hommes tenus à s'acquitter de
> certains devoirs, à rendre de certains services ), comme une
> bourgeoïsie ou une corporation libre , dont tout pouvoir dérive.
>
> (2) I y a donc aussi , suivant ce système, des maîtres et des
> serviteurs dans le monde; seulement les nouveaux philosophes veulent
> mettre les uns à la place des autres.
>
> (3) Constituens est superior constituto. Grotius et Pufendorf
> s'élèvent déjà fortement contre l'application de cette règle , de
> crainte de passer pour révolutionnaires. Mais il n'y a pas moyen de la
> réfuter, dès qu'on part du principe de la délégation du pouvoir. Ils
> allèguent , il est vrai, pour exemple, le tuteur : il est, disent-ils
> , nommé dans l'intérét du pupille , qui cependant est au dessous de
> lui. Mais la comparaison est fausse ; le tuteur n'a point été nommé
> par le pupille, mais par les parens , ou par quelqu'autre autorité qui
> certainement est au dessus de lui.
>
> leur étant confiée par le peuple, ils n?en doivent faire usage que
> pour les intérêts du peuple et jamais pour les leurs propres. L'empire
> même le plus juste exercé par les princes , et sans aucun abus du
> pouvoir, n'est plus un droit, mais une fonction ou un devoir (1), non
> point, comme on le croyait jadis, envers le législateur divin, qui
> est. aussi leur maître, mais envers le peuple, auquel seul ils sont
> responsables de leur administration. La loi, c?est-à-dire, ce qui,
> joint aux devoirs naturels, doit servir à tous ou à plusieurs de règle
> obligatoire dans le lien social, n?est pas la volonté du seigneur ou
> du chef, mais la volonté générale, la volonté de tous les sujets.
> D'après les mêmes principes, les princes ne possèdent plus rien en
> propre (2). Tous leurs
>
> (1) Cest pour cela que les écrivains modernes parlent sans cesse des
> devoirs des princes et des droits des peuples, jamais ils ne disent
> autrement. Ce langage a été transporté même dans les rapports de
> famille; il n'y est à présent question que des devoirs des parens et
> des droits des enfans , comme si les parens n'avaient aucun droit
> propre, et qu'ils eussent été établis par les enfans.
>
> (2) On peut dire d?un souverain, « qu?il ne possède rien » (en propre
> ). Il ne peut avoir des domaines. » Kant. Elém. métaph. de jurisp. p.
> 183. Il ajoute immédiatement
>
> biens , tous leurs revenus viennent également du peuple, et demeurent
> essentiellement la propriété de la nation. Ce sont des contributions
> directes ou indirectes des membres de l'État, uniquement destinées à
> des intérêts nationaux, à des besoins communs, et non point aux
> dépenses particulières des princes. Ce dont ils ont besoin, eux et
> leurs familles, pour jouir d'une existence décente et honorable, ne
> doit être regardé que comme un traitement que le peuple leur accorde,
> en vertu de leur charge. Tous les fonctionnaires et les serviteurs que
> les princes emploient à l'instar des autres hommes, soit pour la
> sûreté ou le soulagement de leur personne, soit pour l'administration
> de leurs biens et de leurs revenus, soit pour la direction de diverses
> autres affaires, deviennent des fonctionnaires publics, des serviteurs
> de l'État , ou du peuple, et c'est à ce nouveau maître fictif qu'ils
> sont responsables de leur conduite. En un mot, tous les États ne sont
> plus que des républiques sous une autre forme, et la chose privée d?un
> prince devient une chose publique (1).

Comment: Please don't post images of text. As you can imagine, this is completely useless to us since we cannot use it to test any solution we come up with. Instead, ***[edit]*** your question and add some representative lines and the output you would expect from those lines.

Comment: Done, my apologies.